# Fonts in C# application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, fonts

I have developed one stand alone application in c#

I need one simple font on which

when user will type in English it will automatically get converted into Marathi or say Devnagari script

Any one knows about specific font???

Is there any specific software on the installation of which above problem will get solved???

i want it as...if user types on keyboard...maz nav raj>>>then display should be ...मझ नाव राज

Comment: It's question not about font, but about text translation. Font is a visual representation of text.

Comment: Its about font...and you are right i want visual representation of text...

Comment: If you dont know the answer....why u downvoted it????

Comment: i want it as...if user types on keyboard...maz nav raj>>>then display should be ...मझ नाव राज

Comment: @ KvanTTT: not ref to you...to whomesoever who downvoted....but if u hav understood my issue...then plz help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use [Google translate API](https://developers.google.com/translate/) or [Bing Translate API](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/using-the-free-bing-translation-apis).

Comment: sir its not online application...its stand alone application...will this work for it?

Comment: @Ray: It will if the end-user has internet connection.

Comment: i dont want translation of language...i want font that will operate as google transliteration operates

Comment: ok...i will try it out...and if any query regarding this wil comment over here...thank you

Comment: i want it as...if user types on keyboard...maz nav raj>>>then display should be ...मझ नाव राज